# Use non-static WebDriver for parallel execution - Selenium - TestNG - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Is this the correct way to initialize a ThreadLocal RemoteWebDriver?

I have seen posts where people say that you should not have a static WebDriver, however, if I remove the static modifier, I end up with NULL pointer exception.

Everything is running fine for the most part, but I am encountering a problem where one thread will occasionally enter data in a different thread. I'm trying to troubleshoot that issue which lead me to this.

**TestSetup class:**

```
public class TestSetup {

    private static ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver> threadDriver;// = new ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>();

    @Parameters({"browserParam"})
    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void beforeClass(@Optional("") final String browserParam) throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException {

        // Set Driver
        threadDriver = new ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>()
        {

            @Override
            protected RemoteWebDriver initialValue()
            {

                String browser = "Chrome";
                DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();

                if (browser.equals("Chrome"))
                {

                    String chromeDriver = "C:\\workspace\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe";
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriver);

                    // Access Grid Hub
                    dc.setBrowserName(DesiredCapabilities.chrome().getBrowserName());

                } // end Chrome

                // Set the driver
                try {
                    threadDriver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubURL), dc));
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return getDriver();

            } // end initialValue

        } // end threadDriver

    } // end beforeClass



    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void afterClass() {

        // Quit the Webdriver
        getDriver().quit();

    } // end afterClass



    public RemoteWebDriver getDriver() {

        return threadDriver.get();

    } // end getDriver

} // end TestSetup class
```

**LoginTest class:**

```
private Function perform = new Function();

@Test (retryAnalyzer = Retry.class, groups={"baseline", "negative"})
public synchronized void loginEmptyUsername() throws InterruptedException {

ExtentTest test = ExtentTestManager.getTest();

// Go to Secure
getDriver().get(StoredVariables.getsecureSite().get());

// Wait for password
perform.waitForElementToBeClickable(SLogin.password_txtbx(), "id");

// Clear email field
SLogin.email_txtbx(getDriver()).clear();

// enter password
SLogin.password_txtbx(getDriver()).clear();
SLogin.password_txtbx(getDriver()).sendKeys(StoredVariables.getpassword().get());

// click Sign In
SLogin.signIn_btn(getDriver()).click();

// Wait for error
perform.waitForElementToBeClickable(SLogin.loginError_txt(), "id");

// Verify error text
Assert.assertTrue(SLogin.loginError_txt(getDriver()).getText().contains("Oops! Your email or password (case sensitive) was incorrect. Please try again."));

// Log test
test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "login", "Tried logging in with an empty email");

} // end loginEmptyUsername
```

How would I pass the WebDriver to the test class if it is not static in the TestSetup class?

**UPDATE:**

It appears that using my initial implementation but restricting the Node to only allow 3 instances as opposed to utilizing the max of 5 instances has resolved my issue (at least for the moment).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be initialising a ThreadLocal from within a method. Your implementation depends on the browser flavor being passed in via the `@BeforeClass` method, which is then being consumed by your initialValue() implementation for instantiating the ThreadLocal and  persisting a WebDriver instance. The problem with this is that the next time when some thread queries your thread local via `get()` and if there's a null value then the call gets routed to `initialValue()` but which now remembers only the last browser param. So your total implementation goes for a toss.

I wrote up a blog post explaining this behavior. Please take a look at it [here](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2016/05/16/a-date-with-threadlocal/).

Also remember that when it comes to guaranteeing the same thread for execution, TestNG extends this guarantee only for `@BeforeMethod` > `@Test` > `@AfterMethod` combination. For everything else, there is no such guarantee.

You can also refer to [this](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/parallel-webdriver-executions-using-testng/) blog of mine, wherein I talk about parallel executions.

The correct way of implementing this should be as below :

```
public class TestSetup {

    private String browserFlavor;

    private static final ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>() {
        @Override
        protected RemoteWebDriver initialValue() {
            //By default lets set the browser flavor always as Chrome.
            return new ChromeDriver();
        }
    };

    @Parameters ({"browserParam"})
    @BeforeClass (alwaysRun = true)
    public void beforeClass(@Optional ("") final String browserParam) {
        this.browserFlavor = browserParam;
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void instantiateBrowser() {
        switch (browserFlavor) {
            case "firefox":
                driver.set(new FirefoxDriver());
                break;
            case "ie":
                driver.set(new InternetExplorerDriver());
                break;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        driver.get().get("http://www.google.com");
    }

}
```

Comment: I implemented your solution (but with the RemoteWebDriver) and am still running into the issue of one thread entering data into another thread, therefore, causing those threads to fail because neither contain the data expected.

Comment: Also, with this setup, say I have 11 classes in my test.xml file and in the xml file I tell it thread-count="2", the first 2 classes run fine, but the rest do not run at all because it says Session ID is null

Comment: @DustinN. You might want to take a look at this blog post of mine https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/parallel-webdriver-executions-using-testng/ for a full fledged solution. Without seeing what you are doing its hard to say whats going wrong. But I can assure you that the solution that I shared does not cause webdriver instances to be leaked across threads.